# app.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one User -- it returned 17

Tags: python, django

I got an error,app.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one User -- it returned 17! .
I wanna parse excel and put it to the model(City&Prefecture&Area&User) . I wrote

```
  fourrows_transpose = list(map(list, zip(*fourrows)))
  val3 = sheet3.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=9)
  user3 = User.objects.get(corporation_id=val3)
  print(user3)
  if user3:
   area = Area.objects.filter(name="America")
   pref = Prefecture.objects.create(name="prefecture", area=user3.area)
   city = City.objects.create(name="city", prefecture=pref)
   price_u1000 = Price.upper1000.objects.get(city=city)
   price_500_1000 = Price.from500to1000.objects.get(city=city)
   price_u500 = Price.under500.objects.get(city=city)

   pref.name = "NY"
   pref.save()

   for i in range(len(fourrows_transpose)):
       city.name = fourrows_transpose[i][1]
       city.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][1])

       price_u1000.name = fourrows_transpose[i][2]
       price_u1000.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][2])

       price_500_1000.name = fourrows_transpose[i][3]
       price_500_1000.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][3])

       price_u500.name = fourrows_transpose[i][4]
       price_u500.save()
       print(fourrows_transpose[i][4])
```

I wanna put these data
`[['America', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', 'u1000', '500～1000', 'd500'], ['NY', 'City A', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City B', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City C', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City D', '×', '×', '×'], ['', 'City E', '×', '×', '×']]`
to models which is like 'America' to Prefecture's area and City A to City's name and ×　to Price's name . How can I fix this?What should I write it?

Comment: Which one of these 17 users do you expect to be returned? what is unclear about the error message?

Comment: you have 17 users in `corporation` is it enough any user to set `Prefecture.area` ?

Comment: @Sayse I think Prefecture.area

Comment: @BearBrown yes,Prefecture.area

Comment: What do Prefectures have to do with returning a single user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to capture first record of instance using this method **first()**

```
user3 = User.objects.filter(corporation_id=val3).first()
```

It helps get first record of Particular object instance, these can be help you

Comment: Have you read the error message ? "get() returned more than one User"

Comment: @Robert I was not the one commenting about the logic being correct for the OP, but the question is still perfectly valid and asserting that it's the "correct" way to solve the problem without knowing anything about the app's business rules is just plain insane - you __cannot__ know if this will yield the expected result.

Comment: @user8563636 you should really think about the implications of such a "solution" before accepting the answer. Actually if you are not 101% positive that choosing just any user at random (from the users associated with that corporation) is ok (in which case your model is certainly wrong in that either `area` should belong to the corporation, not to the user, or that `corporation_id` should be unique per user), you should just stop and ask anyone is in charge what rule should be applied here. "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess".

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
user3 = User.objects.get(corporation_id=val3)
```

You're trying to get a single user, but you have more than one user matching `corporation_id=val3`. Since `objects.get()` cannot guess which one you really want, it does the sensible thing in raising an error with a very explicit message: "get() returned more than one User -- it returned 17"

At this point you have mainly four solutions:

1. get the first user (or the last one or any random one) matching your query (using `User.objects.filter(corporation_id=val3)`.first()`- or`.last()` etc) and call it a day. Well, you can consider it as a solution... kind of... if you don't care about the result that is.
2. make `corporation_id` unique for your `User` model. This means you can only have one single user per corporation, so for each corporation_id you will have to choose one and delete all the others. Well, you can consider it as a solution... kind of... if you don't care about loosing most of your users that is.
3. Add another "use_for_imports" boolean field to your User model, make the combination of this field and corporation_id unique, and change your query to ``User.objects.get(corporation_id=val3, use_for_import=True)`. This will also require that you mark one user as "use for imports" for each corporation, else`get()`will raise a`User.DoesNotExist` exception.
4. Use another user field or combination of fields that is garanteed to be unique for your user lookup, or use another way to get the area (since you only use the user for the `area` field value). Here no one can help since you didn't say anything about your models, requirements etc.